# Deserialize JSON property into different class properties

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am receiving API responses from 3rd party that have ambiguous types. For some methods it is:

```
{"error":{"message":"Resource is already part of this app","status_code":400}}
```

And on other calls it is:

```
{"error": "Resource is already part of this app" }
```

Is it possible to deserialize such responses into something like:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore] //[JsonProperty("error")]
    public ObjectError ObjectError { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectError
{
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status_code")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I have ended up using object as catch all for deserialization.

```
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public object Error { get; set; }

    public string ErrorAsString => Error is string ? Error.ToString() : null;

    public ObjectError ErrorAsObject => Error is string ? null : Error != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectError>(Error.ToString()) : null;
```

It's not ideal, I know.

Comment: are there more than one types of responses? if not then perhaps you can do a `if indexOf("status_code") != -1 then ObjectError else Response`

Comment: @phuzi you are right, I am updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using NetwosoftJson. [Here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) you can check on how to deserialize into an object using it.

You could always parse the JSON object and check to see if it has specific fields. For example:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

if(json.HasKey("message"))
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectError>(jsonString);
    // Do some stuff here
}
else
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: I am aware of how to deserialize objects using NewtonSoft Json. Issue is that same property is sometimes object and sometime it is a string.

Comment: Are those the only two options or are there more variations?

Comment: Those are the only two I have encountered so far.

Comment: Yes that could work as well. I would have to refactor some code. Not ideal, but workable. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deserializing twice. Use json.ToObject<T>() to cast it in the if statement. Also wdym not ideal? What sort of solution did you expect?

Comment: I expected custom deserializer that would be able to prod "error" value and decide whether to populate Error or ObjectError property. But I guess work has to be done someplace, so no solution would be ideal in that sense.